# Why can't I test my action on my phone

Tags: actions-on-google

I finished my first little actions, but I can't test it on my phone. My phone keeps complaining that this app is not available on phones with a german language setting, even though I have an austrian google account linked with it and the app. It works fine inside the simulator though.

My phone is running android 7.0

I hope somebody can help me with this.

**Sreenshots:**

[The working action in the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ousvs.png)

[The error message on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w97g9.png)

Comment: Can you share some screen shots of what it looks like working in the simulator and the error when on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, by switching my language from "german(Austria)" to "german(Germany)".

As it turns out, my phone was "accidentally" running google asisstant. For some reason google asisstant is not available in Austria, but I was able to use it on my phone anyway.